# How can I stop a sprite in pygame from leaving the edge of the screen?

Tags: python, pygame

I have been working on a game and I was wondering how I could make my character stay on screen when I get to the edge of so far it will just keep going off the screen endlessly I am new to python and pygame so I have no clue as to what to do. I have a .png image controlled by user input, I have tried doing

```
if event.type == pygame.K_w and playery > 0:
            playery -= 10
if event.type == pygame.K_s and playery < 1920 - 64:
            playery += 10
if event.type == pygame.K_a and playerx > 0:
            playerx -= 10
if event.type == pygame.K_d and playerx < 1080 - 64:
            playerx += 10
```

but it did not work, here is the code:

```
import pygame
import sys
import os
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.font.init()
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('Music/Start.mp3')
click = pygame.mixer.Sound('Music/Sounds/Click.wav')
pygame.mixer_music.play()

os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = "True"

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
walkRight = [pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_01.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_02.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_03.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_04.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_05.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_06.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_07.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_08.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_09.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_10.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_11.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_12.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_01.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_02.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_03.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_04.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_05.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_06.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_07.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_08.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_09.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_10.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_11.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_12.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_01.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_02.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_03.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_04.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_05.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_06.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_07.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_08.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_09.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_10.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_11.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_12.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_01.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_02.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_03.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_04.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_05.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_06.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_07.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_08.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_09.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_10.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_11.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_12.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_01.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_02.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_03.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_04.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_05.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_06.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_07.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_08.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_09.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_10.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_11.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_12.png')]
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_13.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_14.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_15.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_16.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_17.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_18.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_19.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_20.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_21.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_22.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_23.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_24.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_13.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_14.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_15.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_16.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_17.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_18.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_19.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_20.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_21.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_22.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_23.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_24.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_13.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_14.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_15.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_16.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_17.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_18.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_19.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_20.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_21.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_22.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_23.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_24.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_13.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_14.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_15.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_16.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_17.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_18.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_19.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_20.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_21.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_22.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_23.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_24.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_13.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_14.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_15.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_16.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_17.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_18.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_19.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_20.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_21.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_22.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_23.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_24.png')]
idle = [pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_01_Idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_02_Idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_03_Idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_04_Idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_05_Idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_06_Idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_07_Idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_08_Idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_08_Idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_10_Idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_11_Idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_12_Idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_01_Idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_02_Idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_03_Idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_04_Idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_05_Idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_06_Idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_07_Idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_08_Idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_08_Idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_10_Idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_11_Idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_12_Idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_01_Idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_02_Idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_03_Idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_04_Idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_05_Idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_06_Idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_07_Idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_08_Idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_08_Idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_10_Idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_11_Idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_12_Idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_01_Idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_02_Idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_03_Idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_04_Idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_05_Idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_06_Idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_07_Idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_08_Idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_08_Idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_10_Idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_11_Idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_12_Idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_01_Idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_02_Idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_03_Idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_04_Idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_05_Idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_06_Idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_07_Idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_08_Idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_08_Idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_10_Idle.png'),
        pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_11_Idle.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Wraith_12_Idle.png')]

fullheart = [pygame.image.load('Wraith/Heart.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Heart.png')]
halfheart = [pygame.image.load('Wraith/HalfHeart.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/HalfHeart.png')]
noheart = [pygame.image.load('Wraith/NoHeart.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/NoHeart.png')]

startscreen = pygame.image.load('Wraith/StartScreen.png')

sword = [pygame.image.load('Wraith/Sword.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Sword.png')]
shield = [pygame.image.load('Wraith/Shield.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Shield.png')]

redberries = [pygame.image.load('Wraith/RedBerries.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/RedBerries.png')]
blueberries = [pygame.image.load('Wraith/BlueBerries.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/BlueBerries.png')]

inventory = [pygame.image.load('Wraith/Inventory.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Inventory.png')]
slots = [pygame.image.load('Wraith/Slots.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/Slots.png')]
notequipped = [pygame.image.load('Wraith/NotEquiped.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/NotEquiped.png')]

swordslot = [pygame.image.load("Wraith/SwordSlot.png"), pygame.image.load("Wraith/SwordSlot.png")]
shieldslot = [pygame.image.load('Wraith/ShieldSlot.png'), pygame.image.load('Wraith/ShieldSlot.png')]

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)

font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 18)
newfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Ariel', 150)


new = newfont.render("NEW GAME", True, black)
settings = newfont.render("SETTINGS", True, black)
quit = newfont.render("QUIT", True, black)

WIDTH = 1920
HEIGHT = 1080

playerx = 900
playery = 485


mouseposx = 175
mouseposy = 185

startx = 175
starty = 185


slotx = 175
sloty = 185


walkCount = 0
icon = 1
inv = 0

move_left = False
move_right = False
move_up = False
move_down = False

arangeinventory = False
accessinventory = False
mousepos = False

Heath = 6
ability1 = "Sword"
ability2 = "Shield"
ability3 = "Red Berries"

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), pygame.FULLSCREEN)

game = True
startarea = True


def redrawGameWindow():
    global walkCount
    global icon

    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))

    screen.blit(update_fps(), (1900, 0))

    if walkCount + 1 >= 60:
        walkCount = 0
    if move_right:
        screen.blit(walkRight[walkCount], (playerx, playery))
        walkCount += 1
    elif move_left:
        screen.blit(walkLeft[walkCount], (playerx, playery))
        walkCount += 1
    else:
        screen.blit(idle[walkCount], (playerx, playery))
        walkCount += 1

    if Heath == 6:
        screen.blit(fullheart[icon], (0, 0))
        screen.blit(fullheart[icon], (64, 0))
        screen.blit(fullheart[icon], (128, 0))
    elif Heath == 5:
        screen.blit(fullheart[icon], (0, 0))
        screen.blit(fullheart[icon], (64, 0))
        screen.blit(halfheart[icon], (128, 0))
    elif Heath == 4:
        screen.blit(fullheart[icon], (0, 0))
        screen.blit(fullheart[icon], (64, 0))
        screen.blit(noheart[icon], (128, 0))
    elif Heath == 3:
        screen.blit(fullheart[icon], (0, 0))
        screen.blit(halfheart[icon], (64, 0))
        screen.blit(noheart[icon], (128, 0))
    elif Heath == 2:
        screen.blit(fullheart[icon], (0, 0))
        screen.blit(noheart[icon], (64, 0))
        screen.blit(noheart[icon], (128, 0))
    elif Heath == 1:
        screen.blit(halfheart[icon], (0, 0))
        screen.blit(noheart[icon], (64, 0))
        screen.blit(noheart[icon], (128, 0))

    if ability1 == "Sword":
        screen.blit(sword[icon], (1728, 888))
    if ability2 == "Shield":
        screen.blit(shield[icon], (1792, 760))
    if ability3 == "Red Berries":
        screen.blit(redberries[icon], (1601, 952))
    elif ability3 == "Blue Berries":
        screen.blit(blueberries[icon], (1601, 952))

    if accessinventory:
        screen.blit(inventory[icon], (0, 0))
        screen.blit(slots[icon], (175, 185))
        screen.blit(slots[icon], (769, 185))
        screen.blit(slots[icon], (1263, 185))
        screen.blit(swordslot[icon], (slotx, sloty))
        screen.blit(shieldslot[icon], (769, 185))
    pygame.display.update()



def update_fps():
    fps = str(int(clock.get_fps()))
    fps_text = font.render(fps, 1, white)
    return fps_text
screen.blit(startscreen, (0, 0))
screen.blit(new, (650, 488))
screen.blit(quit, (790, 888))
while game:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        while startarea:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    startx, starty = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    if startx >= 624 and startx <= 1257 and starty >= 855 and starty <= 1028:
                        click.play()
                        sys.exit()
                    elif startx >= 624 and startx <= 1257 and starty >= 445 and starty <= 618:
                        click.play()
                        bg = pygame.image.load('Ground/BG.png')
                        startarea = False
                    else:
                        None
            pygame.display.update()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                move_left = True
                move_right = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                move_right = True
                move_left = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                move_up = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                move_down = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_i:
                inv += 1
            elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                move_left = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                move_right = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                move_up = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                move_down = False

        if (inv % 2) == 0:
            arangeinventory = False
            accessinventory = False
        else:
            arangeinventory = True
            accessinventory = True




    if move_left:
        playerx -= 10
    if move_right:
        playerx += 10
    if move_up:
        playery -= 10
    if move_down:
        playery += 10

    redrawGameWindow()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your if statements that move the player. Changed them so it only changes the x and y if they are within the screen still. Like so:

```py
    if move_left and playerx>0:
        playerx -= 10
    if move_right and playerx<(1920-64):
        playerx += 10
    if move_up and playery>0:
        playery -= 10
    if move_down and playery<(1080-64):
        playery += 10
```

This will only allow the player to move if they aren't going out of the screen

Comment: Thank you for the help!